# How to implement multiple actions listeners without inner classes?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm pretty new to Java and I would like to know if it's possible to use multiple action listeners in the same class(for instance when using multiple JButton objects) without using inner classes. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is pretty broad and on face value could be answered simply "yes".  You need to give a bit of context for your question (what are you trying to achieve) and some detail to show what you've tried so far and where your problem is occurring.  See here for ideas to give a little more detail in a good question http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JRichardSnape Thank you, I will consider this question answer for now and come back with more information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. It's possible. You could implement the `ActionListener`(s) with only external classes on your classpath or with lambdas in Java 8.

```
public class MyListener implements ActionListener {
  // ..
}
```

and then something like

```
btn.addActionListener(new MyListener());
```

or (using Java 8+) a lambda like

```
btn.addActionListener(ae -> { System.out.println("Button Clicked"); });
```

Comment: Ok so there's other ways, but is inner classes the most effective way of doing it? Or is it just consuming more memory, that's really why I asked the question, I feel like inner classes consume a lot of it and I wanted to know if there's another less memory consuming method.

Comment: Inner classes consume exactly the same amount of memory as non-inner classes. What makes you *feel* differently?

Comment: I'm not talking about classes, i'm talking about in general what's the most efficient way to use action listeners so that they don't consume as much memory?

Comment: @user4442652 Java uses a dynamic memory model and you can't explicitly manage it. In general, the most efficient way to not consume as much memory is to not consume so much memory.

Comment: The memory consumption of listeners is irrelevant in a real life application. You can use profiling tools to [generate and analyze a heap dump](http://visualvm.java.net/heapdump.html) of a running application and you will soon find out how negligible the memory consumption of listeners is.

Answer (score 1):

Using Java 8 you can use lambda expressions for implementing listeners like this:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ActionListenerExample {
    ActionListenerExample() {
        JTextField tf=new JTextField();
        tf.addActionListener(ev -> textAction(tf));
        JButton b=new JButton();
        b.addActionListener(this::buttonClicked);
    }

    private void textAction(JTextField tf) {

    }
    private void buttonClicked(ActionEvent ev) {

    }
}
```

But even before Java 8 there was an option to generate listeners dynamically:

```
import static java.beans.EventHandler.*;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class ActionListenerExample1 {
    ActionListenerExample1() {
        JTextField tf=new JTextField();
        tf.addActionListener(create(ActionListener.class,this,"textAction","source"));
        JButton b=new JButton();
        b.addActionListener(create(ActionListener.class, this, "buttonClicked", ""));
    }

    public void textAction(JTextField tf) {
        System.out.println(tf);
    }
    public void buttonClicked(ActionEvent ev) {
        System.out.println(ev);
    }
}
```

It has higher overhead and lacks compile-time safety but on the other hand, it can generate listeners with multiple listening methods while lambda expression support only one listener method.

Comment: Ok so there's other ways, but is inner classes the most effective way of doing it? Or is it just consuming more memory, that's really why I asked the question, I feel like inner classes consume a lot of it and I wanted to know if there's another less memory consuming method

Comment: It depends on how you define efficiency. Using a lambda expression is the most efficient way in most cases but, as said, it requires Java 8 and works for single method interfaces like `ActionListener` only. For other cases, generating listeners via `java.beans.EventHandler` will reduce the application’s code size and may reduce the initialization time but at higher costs at runtime. There’s also the option of using a top-level class rather than an inner class. That would raise the amount of source code but yield to smaller class files compared to inner classes.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create your own `MyButton` object which *extends* `JButton` and *implements* `ActionListener` and then use it instead of a simple `JButton`:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;


public class MyButton extends JButton implements ActionListener
{
    public MyButton() {
        super();
        addActionListener(this);
    }

    @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Now `MyButton` has a custom behavior.

Comment: Implementing a listener `interface` without registering the listener on a source has no effect. And letting the source component implement the listener `interface` would require registering the component on itself as a listener which is a bad coding practice.

Comment: Yes, you're right, I forgot to register the button to the listener. just edited.